# Split URI query string like they are filters ?title=php_filter&size>2&author!=smith

Tags: php, uri, query-string, explode

My google-fu is failing me today. I'm looking to parse a query sting like:

```
https://example.com/some/path/here?title=my_title&size>2&author!=smith
```

I'm looking to the parse the query string into:

```
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["operator"]=>
    string(1) "="
    ["search"]=>
    string(8) "my_title"
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["operator"]=>
    string(1) ">"
    ["search"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["author"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["operator"]=>
    string(2) "!="
    ["search"]=>
    string(5) "smith"
  }
}
```

The possible operators are mostly the standard php ones: ==, !=, <>, >, <, >=, <=

Any pointers on parsing this?  Thanks.

**Edit 1:**  Thanks Armin Sam. My original URL needed a urldecode tossed in there, but otherwise, it's working fine.

```
function parseURLAsFilters($url) {
    $url = urldecode($url);
    $result = [];
    $queries = explode('&', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
    $pattern = '/(==|=|>=|<=|<>|<|>|!=)/';

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $queryArray = preg_split($pattern, $query, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $result[$queryArray[0]] = [
            'operator' => $queryArray[1],
            'search' => $queryArray[2]
        ];
    }

    return $result; 
}
```

PS: I tried to up vote your answer, but i'm not ranked high enough for the score to take effect.

Comment: Use php superglobal variables $_GET, $_REQUEST. Also operators are not passed in the url, pass only the variables, and do the logic, implode, explode in php

Comment: I have no problem getting the entire query string. Im stuck on parsing it into a array given that its not just an equal sign...but a list of possible delimiters.

Comment: That is what I have said, you cannot pass operators (==, !=, <>, >, <, >=, <= ) in url ($_GET). Use some other means to pass your data. How about serialize() data and pass it with $_POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function that might get you the result you're looking for. I haven't tested it, so there might be some small issues which I'm sure you can fix.

```php
function parseUrl($url) {
    $result = [];
    $queries = explode('&', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
    $pattern = '/(==|=|>=|<=|<>|<|>|!=)/';

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $queryArray = preg_split($pattern, $query, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $result[$queryArray[0]] = [
            'operator' => $queryArray[1],
            'search' => $queryArray[2]
        ];
    }

    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: There is an $ signg mising

`$result[queryArray[0]] = [
            'operator' => queryArray[1],
            'search' => queryArray[2]
        ];`

Comment: Yea, I noticed. Updated the answer, you can try again.